# Child Theme CSS Not Overriding Parent Theme In MultiSite Site

Tags: multisite, child-theme, css, parent-theme

I've been banging my head on the wall for a while now trying to figure this out.  I have a multisite setup currently with just the main site and a network site I added.  The main site displays just fine, however the network site I added has a few elements, like the sidebar, that are using the parent themes stylesheet.

Specifics:

1. I'm using a multisite setup with subdomains.
2. I'm using the twentyeleven theme with a child theme
3. I did copy the wp_posts, wp_postmeta, wp_term_relationships and wp_term_taxonomy tables over from the main site to the network site.  Not sure if that had something to do with it.

I ran firebug on the network site and the css and html came back with no errors

Here is the main site: http://onlinechimpwebsitesolution.com/
And here is the network site: http://sitetemplate.onlinechimpwebsitesolution.com/

The two should look identical.

As you can see, the network sites sidebar is floated right when it should be left, as specified in the child themes stylesheet. Also the content and sidebar widths are being pulled from the parent themes stylesheet.

I'm at a loss here.... Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: As-written, this question is **off-topic** as a purely CSS/HTML question. Please post relevant code, including any modified template-part files (i.e. `header.php`) and any functions used to *enqueue stylesheets* in the Child Theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The markup on the two sites is different. The main site, using your labels, has a `body_class` of `left-sidebar`, the network site as a `body_class` of `right-sidebar`.

I'd call this a pure CSS/markup issue except that you are dealing with [`body_class`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class) so either there is a theme setting that did not transfer or something has been altered in a template file or a filter.

Comment: Exactly right, the layout setting for the parent theme didn't transfer over.  Thanks for the help!