# Force remove parent theme CSS/JS and call them from Child theme

Tags: plugin-development, multisite

I'm using multi site with only one site.
I want to force my parent theme NOT to call any css/js. In the same time I want to force my child theme to include the new CSS/JS using its function.php file.

I saw many advice across this great portal but none of them works with me.
My problem that I couldn't prevent the parent theme function.php to stop loading CSS/JS

Can you please explain with example once for CSS and one for Js?

Thank you.

Comment: what parent theme are you using?

Comment: I'm using pointfinder and it has dynamic css

Comment: as you are using a commercial parent theme, consider to contact the theme's developer for help.

Comment: you say: "I couldn't prevent the parent theme function.php to stop loading CSS/JS" why? How does the parent theme loads CSS/JS? Cany post the code?

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/101691/child-theme-css-not-overriding-parent-theme-in-multisite-site?rq=1

Comment: You are right, I asked stupid question and I hope I did not :( Thank you so much for the advises. And I will really think a lot before asking new questions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the handle of the stylesheet will be the ID given to the  element in the markup. If you can't find the enqueue function in the mothertheme you can inspect the site to find it.

If you have the ID you can use :

```
add_action('wp_footer', function() {
   wp_dequeue_style('the_id_of_the_stylesheet');
});
```